# Vue.js Как получить содержимое ячейки по клику в генерируемой таблице drag and drop

Tags: vue.js, table, drag, drop

Таблица drag and drop, в которой можно перетаскивать ячейки вместе с содержимым. Решение работает относительно одного объекта который перемещается. Чтобы двигался второй объект я поместил его id в разметку с намерением сделать далее его невидимым.Цель получать по клику id в разметке и фильтровать нужный объект по id, которому нужно изменить положение по координатам position_x и position_y.  Код ниже

```
    <div>
          <table>
            <tr v-for="(row, i) in table">
                <td draggable="true"
                    :key="j"
                    :data-row="i"
                    :data-ceil="i"
                    @drag.start="drag"
                    @dragover.prevent
                    @drop.stop="drop"
                    v-for="(item,  j) in row">
                    <div class='item' v-if="item">
                    <div class='id'>{{item.id}}</div><br>{{item.name}}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</template>
<script>
 import _ from "lodash";
    export default {
        name: "Storage",
        props: [],
        data() {
            return {               
                size: [8, 8],                
                displayed: false,               
                currentTarget: [],
                nextTarget: [],
                currentPosItem: {},                
                 items:  [
                        {
                            id: 4,                           
                            name: "Queen",
                            quantity: 4,
                            position_x: 3,
                            position_y: 2,

                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,                            
                            name: "Queen",
                            quantity: 1,
                            position_x: 0,
                            position_y: 0,                            
                        }

                    ]

            }
        },

        computed: {

            table: function () {
                const map = [];
                for (let x = 0; x < this.size[0]; x++) {
                    map.push(_.fill(Array(this.size[1]), null));
                }
                _.forEach(this.items, (item) => {
                    if (item.position_x !== -1 && item.position_y !== -1)
                        map[item.position_x][item.position_y] = item;                      
                    this.currentPosItem = item;
                    if (item.position_x !== -1 && item.position_y !== -1)
                        map[item.position_x][item.position_y] = this.currentPosItem;
                });
                return map;
            },

        },
        methods: {          

            drag(event) {
                let target = event.target
                let i = target.dataset.row;
                let j = target.dataset.ceil;
                this.currentTarget = [j, i];
               //if (cell.tagName != 'SPAN') return;            
                let td = target.textContext;  
                console.log(td)                
            },
            drop(event) {  
                let target = event.target              
               // console.log(cell);
                let m = target.parentNode.rowIndex;
                let n = target.cellIndex;
                this.nextTarget = [m, n];
                this.currentPosItem.position_x = m;
                this.currentPosItem.position_y = n;
                console.log(this.currentPosItem);
            }
        },
    };
</script>


<style scoped>
    table {
        width: auto;
    }
    td {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

  .id{
    background-color: yellow;
 }
</style>
```

Прослущиватель события клика уже есть в элементе td 
Здесь @drag.start="drag". Нужно получить содержимое дочернего элемента td, в котором выводится item.id.  Пробовал  target.textContext,  target.innerHTML, target.closest(selectors). Безрезультатно.

Answer (score 0):

Изменения в функции drop(), но фокус на элементе в html срабатывает нечетко. Пока не знаю как улучшить решение.

```
drop(event) {               
                let sheet=document.querySelector("#id");
                var id = sheet.textContent; 
                console.log(id); 
                this.currentPosItem= this.currentItem.find(itm => itm.id == id)   
                console.log(this.currentPosItem) 
                let target = event.target;                           
                let m = target.parentNode.rowIndex;
                let n = target.cellIndex;
                this.nextTarget = [m, n];
                this.currentPosItem.position_x = m;
                this.currentPosItem.position_y = n;
                //console.log(this.currentPosItem.id);
                this.currentItem.length=0;                  
            }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить изменения в разметке:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- table1 - content table -->
        <table ID='tbl'>
            <tr v-for="(row, i) in table">
                <td draggable="true"
                    :key="j"
                    :data-row="i"
                    :data-ceil="i"
                    @drag.start="drag"
                    @dragover.prevent
                    @drop.stop="drop"
                    v-for="(item,  j) in row">
                    <div id='item' v-if="item">
                    <div id='id'>{{item.id}}</div><br>{{item.name}}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>        
    </div>
</template>
```

изменения в data:

```
 data() {
            return {               
                size: [8, 8],                
                displayed: false,               
                currentTarget: [],
                nextTarget: [],
                currentPosItem: {}, 
                currentItem: [],              
                 items:  [
                        {
                            id: 4,                           
                            name: "Queen",
                            quantity: 4,
                            position_x: 3,
                            position_y: 2,

                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,                            
                            name: "Queen",
                            quantity: 1,
                            position_x: 0,
                            position_y: 0,                            
                        }

                    ]

            }
```

изменения в computed:

```
computed: {

            table: function () {
                const map = [];
                for (let x = 0; x < this.size[0]; x++) {
                    map.push(_.fill(Array(this.size[1]), null));
                }
                _.forEach(this.items, (item) => {
                    if (item.position_x !== -1 && item.position_y !== -1)
                        map[item.position_x][item.position_y] = item;
                    this.currentPosItem = item;                 
                    this.currentItem.push(this.currentPosItem)                    
                    //console.log(this.currentItem)
                });
                return map;
              }
           },
```